# Why need COPY Gemfile in Dockerfile to docker while set volumes in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I followed https://docs.docker.com/samples/rails/ to setup docker environment.

I found it set `WORKDIR /myapp` in *Dockerfile* and set volumes mount in docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
```

Why still need config these two COPY commands to invoke `RUN bundle install` ??

```
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
```

If I remove it from Dockerfile, when I run `docker compose build`, got following error:

```
 => ERROR [5/5] RUN bundle install                                                                                                                                                                     0.7s
------
 > [5/5] RUN bundle install:
#9 0.629 Could not locate Gemfile
```

Is there no `Gemfile` file in docker /myapp directory? Volumes mount not worked? I thought after I set volumes mount in docker-compose.yml, the Gemfile and other source code files should exist in */myapp* directory.

Comment: The `volumes:` hide whatever you `COPY` into the image, which makes the image not especially useful.  Would a non-Docker version manager like `rbenv` or `rvm` work better for day-to-day development, and then you can delete the `volumes:` block for Docker-based integration testing?

Comment: (The logical conclusion to the question you ask is that the `COPY` isn't useful, because it will just get hidden by the mount; but that reduces the Dockerfile to just `FROM ruby` plus a bind mount; and if you want to run Ruby on host code, the version managers provide a more convenient way to do that than Docker.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volumes are only mounted at *run-time*. The `RUN bundle install` command is run at *build-time* where the mounted volume isn't available.

I often recommend keeping building and running the image separate, since it can be confusing what is used when.